# VBA Excel: Concatenate a range of cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to concatenate a range of cells along a single row. This group of cells has a defined start but a variable end. I tried doing this, but it didn't work. I'm still learning the Syntax of VBA but I haven't seen anything that says this WON'T work. Any help is appreciated.

```
Dim hexVal As String

For i = 4 To N + 3
    Cells(3, i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Dec2Hex(Cells(2, i), 2) & " "
Next i

hexVal = CONCATENATE(Range(Cells(3,i),Cells(3,N+3))

End Sub
```

Comment: Inside you're loop, you are repeatedly overwriting the value in `Cells(3, i)`.  That is probably a mistake. Can you elaborate on what your particular problem is? Perhaps by giving examples of the data and the desired results?

Comment: @DavidZemens That's not the issue. The issue is in the syntax. Before I even run the code, I get an error related to the CONCATENATE command "seperator or )" expected

Comment: Using `i` outside of its loop is horribly wrong. Consider copying its value on another variable for further use. Also, @DavidZemens, `Cells(3, i)` isn't getting overwritten, it isnt `Cell(I3)`, it is `Cells(3, 4)`, then `Cells(3, 5)` and so on. (Its `i`from the loop, not the column "I")

Comment: OK then this problem is a duplicate of something I've answered about 10 times already this week. Hold on, I will point you in the right direction.

Comment: @DavidZemens Ah ok. Sorry for the trouble but thanks!

Comment: no worries I just wish I could find one of my other answers rather than type it out again :0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need Concatenate(), but using **&** instead:

```
for i = 4 to N + 3
  hexVal = hexVal & cells(3,i)
next i
```

That is in case you are just concatenate the strings and you do know the range needs to be concatenate.

Answer (score 3):

HEre's your problem:

```
CONCATENATE(Range(Cells(3,i),Cells(3,N+3))
```

The `Cells` method returns a range object, the default property of which is the `.Value` property. So, this is equivalent to:

```
CONCATENATE(Range(Cells(3,i).Value,Cells(3,N+3).Value)
```

As such, it will **ALWAYS FAIL** unless those cells contain a valid address string.

**Solution ...** just use the built-in concatenator

```
hexVal = Range(Cells(3,i) & Cells(3,N+3))
```

Or:

```
hexVal = CONCATENATE(Range(Cells(3,i).Value,Cells(3,N+3).Value))
```

Comment: Ah ok makes sense. So I wasn't telling the program what to do with the cells?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If you don't specify a property, then VBA will rely on the default property, which in this case is the `.Value`.

Comment: I like Alex's solution better, there is usually more than one "solution" to a problem in VBA, but figured this might be useful to you anyways in explaining *why* it wasn't working.  Cheers.

Comment: +1 to explaining the actual problem.  Also not a big deal but there's a missing ")" on both answers~